# A good way to use session$token from ShinyApp?

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following application [image: here] that stores a users session token and randomly generates a document ID. I am hoping to get advice on how best to use them.

My desire is to use the session token to identify users in other applications: This will serve to filter selections of data to ensure users can only select documents they have submitted.

I have had success with this using persistent cookies - but, I discovered today that if a user first navigates to my app, this does not work (I was storing the persistent cookie from App 1 & App 2 and using a master database to find the common variable 'persistent cookie'). This method failed today during testing when the app site was navigated to before any other, leaving the persistent cookie nonexistent.

Is there a way to use the token to identify users in subsequent applications?

Comment: Up front, I don't know ... but is that a field that a malicious use can modify and submit? (Cookies, http params, etc.)

Comment: are you referring to the input$id param? The sessionid is auto generated.